# How can I limit the number of results returned from LEFT JOIN without a sub select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query but it's returning multiple entries from the profile_photos table.  Is it possible to return just one **random** entry from the profile photos table? If not random is it possible to limit the number of results to 1?

Here is my current query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login_users " .
       "LEFT JOIN profile_photos ON profile_photos.user_id = login_users.user_id " .
       "LEFT JOIN profiles ON profiles.user_id = login_users.user_id " .
       "WHERE login_users.restricted <> 1 " .
       "ORDER BY login_users.birthdate DESC " .
       "LIMIT 0, 20";
```

Comment: The keywords you are searching for are `RAND()` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: how about changing the `LIMIT 0, 20` to `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: I'm looking for 20 results but currently each individual result can vary depending on the number of photos tied to each profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method.  Look up a random photo and then join in the additional information:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select lu.*,
             (select photo_id
              from profile_photos
              where lu.user_id = profile_photos.user_id
              order by RAND()
              limit 1
             ) as photo_id
      from login_users lu
     ) lu LEFT JOIN
     profile_photos pp
     ON pp.photo_id = lu.photo_id LEFT JOIN
     profiles p
     ON p.user_id = lu.user_id 
WHERE lu.restricted <> 1
ORDER BY lu.birthdate DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

This assumes that photo_id is the primary key on profile_photos.

Comment: +1 : I just finished typing that in SQL Fiddle on another laptop, but you had it done already. You nippy typer you :)

Comment: hmm...it's complaining about unknown lu table.  Should I move the lu after the login_users?

Comment: @Paul - The `lu.*` should be `login_users.*`

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Post your edit... Your inner most query still references `login_users` which is now aliased to `lu`. You also use the alias `lu` twice : for both a sub-query and the login_users table *(not an error, but may confuse a human being when mis-reading the scope that a particular `lu` reference pertains to)*.

Comment: @Dems.  Do you still have your SQL Fiddle? I'm still getting errors.

Comment: @Paul - www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf538/4

Comment: @Dems, Thanks! That works without error and gets me started in the right direction.  Thanks again!